# Null error adding record to database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ado.net

I have the following application that loads a customer record based on a search.A new invoice can then be added using the fields shown.

But when I go to add a new invoice record I get a "noNullAllowedException" on the invoiceNumber column. I'm not sure why I'm getting this error as when adding a new invoice I change the default -1 value to  '11' for example and change the other default invoice options.

I checked the columns properties to check if it stemmed from a conflicting setting but it seems fine.Does anyone know where I'm going wrong with the validation,that it is giving this result?

[image: Default form settings:]

[image: Invoice user input:]

[image: Resulting error:]

[image: Dataset schema]

This is the code behind the invoice add method:

```
private void addInvoice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Check that the line item data is valid
   if (IsValidLineItem())
   {
      // Add a new row to the InvoiceLineItems table
      lineItemsBindingSource.AddNew();

      // Set the values of the row in the data grid
      int rowIndex = lineItemsDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1;
      DataGridViewRow row = lineItemsDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex];

      DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[0];
      cell.Value = 1;
      cell = row.Cells[1];
      cell.Value = productIDComboBox.SelectedValue; // not Index
      cell = row.Cells[2];
      cell.Value = unitPriceTextBox.Text;
      cell = row.Cells[3];
      cell.Value = quantityTextBox.Text;
      cell = row.Cells[4];
      cell.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(unitPriceTextBox.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(quantityTextBox.Text);    

      // Save the line item to the table
      lineItemsBindingSource.EndEdit();

      // Calculate the invoice total
      this.GetInvoiceTotal();

      // Prepare for the next entry
      quantityTextBox.Text = "";
      quantityTextBox.Focus();
   }
}
```

Comment: Dump your table scheme as well, might help us.

Comment: Where are you inserting InvoiceNumber?  I don't see it listed in your code...

Comment: Where do you set the value for `InvoiceNumber`?  I don't see any line of code doing that.  At least not obviously doing that, this all looks very loosely-typed and loosely-named.

Comment: Ok,I'll make those edits now.

Comment: how is lineItemsDataGridView tied to the database? It looks like you are setting the value correctly (setting it to 1), but how is it tied back to the database?

Comment: @user2932397 I'm not sure by what you mean "tied".My understanding is that lineItemsDataGridView  is a table from the database I'm using, so I shouldn't have to do anything else other than drag and drop it to the form?  Am I missing a step somewhere? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparantly, one of the assignments is setting the cell value to *null*.

```
cell.Value = productIDComboBox.SelectedValue; // not Index
...
cell.Value = unitPriceTextBox.Text;
...
cell.Value = quantityTextBox.Text;
```

If you know which column is the "InvoiceNumber", then you will have your culprit.

Comment: looks to me like the one which is InvoiceNumber is 0, which he is hard coding to 1.

Comment: But the integer value 1 is not null (it will get boxed as an object when assigned to DataGridViewCell.Value, which is of type object). But there is certainly a bug/mistake in how/from which data sources he sets the individual cells.

Comment: I tried editing the assignment to: `DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[0];
                cell.Value = invoiceNumberTextBox.Text;` But I'm still getting the same exception.

Comment: is your lineItemsDataGridView tied back to the database at all? you could be setting the values correctly, just that they aren't the ones being put into the database.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by tied back? I added the `lineItemsDataGridView` from the database connected to the application.Is there a step I may have missed here?

Comment: @elgonzo,I don't think this is the problem as I took this code snippet from a working replica of this application.I just can't see where I've gone wrong up to this point in adding an invoice.

Comment: @Brian, are you certain? Have you run the debugger and stepped through the code with the data that causes the exception, and checked what those assignments do? Or are you just guessing (like me)?

Comment: @Brian, while you are at it, please check which Column `Index` the "InvoiceNumber" column has. We know from the screenshot that its `DisplayIndex` is 0, but the actual `Index` (which is used to access the cells) might be different (although the DB model hints at the Index being 0 as well).

Comment: @Brian, now i am doing wild speculations (sorry ;) ): Perhaps the error is misleading; check please also if the InvoiceNumber you enter corresponds with an existing invoice in the "Invoices" table. If InvoiceNumber is the primary key of the "Invoices" table, then the DB might perhaps prevent you from adding records to the "LineItems" table/view whose InvoiceNumber does not match an existing primary key in the "Invoices" table.

Comment: I figured it out I think,I forgot to disable deleting,adding etc from the smart tag of the lineItemsDataGrid.